# Find the number of lattice paths from a point to another defined by a Line

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have a question that requires me to figure out the number of lattice paths from a single point to a point on a line and i'm having trouble figuring out the exact solution.

I know the lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,m)$ is ${n + m \choose n}$ but I'm wondering what if we were to go from a point say $(0,0)$ to a point defined by $(x,y)$ on a line where $x=m$ and $1 \leq y \leq n$. What would be the number of lattice paths? (as pointed out by the comment, consider being able to move upwards upon hitting the $x=m$ line as possible lattice paths).

Also as a follow up, what would be the number of lattice paths from given by a point on a line, to a point (the inverse scenario)?

Any insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to take steps upward after you reach the line $x=m$, or must you stop as soon as you hit it?

Comment: Good question, I should have specified but yes I believe we can take steps upward once we hit the line $x=m$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a path can move up the line $x=m$ after it hits it, this is clearly just the sum of the ways to reach the points $\langle m,k\rangle$ with $1\le k\le n$, or

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{m+k}m\;;$$

I’ll leave it to you to get a closed form for this using the hockey stick lemma. (Be a little careful: the sum starts at $k=1$, not $k=0$.)

If the path has to stop as soon as it hits the line $x=m$, we have to be a little more careful: a path that terminates at $\langle m,k\rangle$ must have reached that point from $\langle m-1,k\rangle$, which it could have reached by any legal path. In this case we would count

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{m-1+k}{m-1}$$

paths, which can be simplified similarly.

In both cases you will need to make a minor adjustment if you want to include the path terminating at $\langle m,0\rangle$.